# cursor.to_dict() works when converting my SQL query cursor to a dict. dict(cursor) does not. Why is this?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, dictionary, cursors

```
 with giraffez.Cmd() as cmd:
    cmd.execute(APP_ID_TABLE)
    results2 = cmd.execute(Query2)
    x = list(dict(results2))
    print(x)
```

"Results" is a cursor object that to me looks like a collection of dictionaries so first off I don't know why I can't convert it directly to a list.

But the real question is why results2.to_dict() works like a charm but dict(results) does not. Any clue?

The error is: *dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required*

Comment: Iterating over the cursor needs to produce a sequence of (key, value) records if it's to be consumed by the `dict()` constructor. It doesn't. As the error message says, it produces sequences of single items. That's why `to_dict()` exists.

Comment: Thank you. What is different about the functionality of to_dict() that allows it to work?

Comment: It's written so that it works? I'm not sure what you're asking, really.

Comment: dict() requires > 1 in order to identify keys correct? So how does to_dict() identify keys if it reads values one by one?

Comment: `to_dict()` is probably not using the cursor's default iteration or the `dict` constructor. You could look at the source and see...